# Dell Latitude E7440 not picking up new router WiFi signal but other devices can connect to it

Tags: wireless-networking, laptop, wireless-router, troubleshooting

I have a new ZTE 5G router. My laptop (Dell Latitude E7440) cannot pick up the WiFi signal, yet my wife’s laptop and my phone does.

My laptop does pick up my phone’s hotspot and every other signal in the building, just not the new router.

Why am I unable to see it or connect to it?

The network card in the laptop is an [Intel Dual Band AC 7260](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/75439/intel-dual-band-wirelessac-7260.html) card.

The router is a ZTE MC801A 4G/5G router and the details of this device are below.

- **Network**: NSA&SA 5G: n41/78/79/1/28. 4G: B1/3/5/8/28/34/39/40
- **Dimensions**: 182mmx124mmx70mm
- **Wi-Fi**: Wi-Fi 6, 2.4G and 5G dual band, 2*2 MIMO 1.775GBbps, 32 users
- **Antenna**: 3.5GHz band max gain up to 9dBi (optional)

I’m not sure if I’m seeing correctly or I just don’t understand hardware, but it seems as if they both support 802.11N. What I'm not sure of is the NSA&SA 5G: n <- part, if that's the same as 802.11N

Honestly this router has very minimal settings. I’m comparing it to my old Huawei router and this one comes up really short on options. I’m not sure there is a way to change much but below is the screenshot of my router's advanced settings.

[image: Screenshot.]

This first screen shows you that I’m connected to the internet even though I”ve got no wifi available. And it shows you things I can click on that might be of interest.

The second screen below is to show you literally all the options under 'Router'.

This router software is pretty bare bones.

[image: Screenshot.]

Below is a screenshot taken from my phone of the network tools panel on the router.

[image: Screenshot.]

Comment: Try a USB Wireless Card (new one) and see if that connects

Comment: The laptop is too old to support the latest wifi protocols. Enter the router login page and see if you can enable the protocols called B, G and N (all of them since I don't know which ones your laptop can use). What model exactly is the router?

Comment: Yes and that is why I suggested a new Wireless USB card to demonstrate this,

Comment: @harrymc ZTE MC810A not sure how to enable all wifi protocols

Comment: @Chamkey - You shouldn't have to enable "all WiFI protocols" WiFI 6 for instance is backward compatible with WiFI. Can you provide the model information for all adapters and routers?  Be as specific as possible.  By calling it "5G" you made it sound like you were trying to use a 5G hotspot.  You should address that confusion by providing the exact ZTE router you purchased.

Comment: So I was correct in my assumption.  You didn't purchase a WiFI 6 router, you purchased a 5G router, that shares the 5G connection to other devices through WIFi 6.  You are aware of this?

Comment: @Ramhound, I'm aware that I'm using a router that connects me to the internet via a 5G sim card. I do not know what wifi 6 is. I did however try to troubleshoot the problem a little while ago and it did mention wifi 6. I just got done downloading the latest drivers for my system. I'll let you know if that fixes anything.

Comment: From the little information available, this router *should* support your laptop. The network adapter of the laptop is fine.

Comment: @Chamkey - WiFi6 is simply the current revision of 802.11, it's now called WiFi (4,5,6,ect) instead of 802.11 (g,ac,ax,ect).  Can you provide screenshots of the configuration page of the access point provided they are in English?

Comment: The device in your screenshot has an Ethernet adapter, which is the reason, it’s able to communicate with the access point. The modes you are looking for should be in Network Tools.

Comment: Yes it does have an ethernet adapter but that's not the reason why i'm connected to the internet. I'm using bluetooth tethering. Secondly, I don't have a network cable with me so, a network cable is unplugged. What I'm doing is connecting to my phone via bluetooth tethering. My phone is sharing its connection to the router to my laptop.  My laptop itself cannot find the wifi connection that my phone can. Third, my laptop can find other networks, like my phone when I use my phone as a hotspot. I'm trying to cut my phone out of the picture and directly connect to the router with my laptop.

Comment: “What I'm not sure of is the NSA&SA 5G: n <- part, if that's the same as 802.11N” What the 4G/5G connection is ha 100% nothing to do with the Wi-Fi connection. The Wi-Fi connection would be spec’ed out as something like “802.11” or “Wi-Fi 6” and such.